Why is my oscilloscope math mode showing an RMS voltage in gigavolts (unexpectedly high value)
I'm experiencing an issue with my Rigol DS1202 oscilloscope. When using the math function to measure the RMS voltage of the difference between two channels (A - B), the RMS value is displayed in gigavolts (GV) instead of volts (V). This is puzzling because the RMS measurements for Channel 1 (CH1) and Channel 2 (CH2) are correct and displayed in volts. When there is no power across the resistor I am measuring, and there is just noise, the VRMS for the math mode jumps between 0 and some megavolt value...
Here's a summary of my setup and the steps I've taken to troubleshoot this issue:
Setup:
Oscilloscope: Rigol DS1202
Probes: 1x attenuation, correctly compensated. I am measuring the signal across a resistor (CH1 on one side, and CH2 on the other, to calculate the RMS voltage drop across it. I haven't connected the grounds to anything)
Signal: CH1 measures a signal with approximately 1V RMS, and CH2 measures a signal with approximately 6V RMS. The signal is a burst modulated waveform at 25.5kHz carrier, and 200Hz modulation.
Issue:
The RMS measurement for CH1 is around 1V, which sounds right.
The RMS measurement for CH2 is around 6V, which sounds right.
The RMS measurement for the math function A - B (CH2-CH1) is incorrectly displayed in gigavolts (e.g., 2.52GV).
I have previously made correct measurements in volts, and now the numbers seem correct, but the units in GV so it seems to be scaled up for some reason.
Troubleshooting Steps:

The waveform is stable and properly triggered on CH2, with a holdoff of 6ms so that it waits till the next burst to trigger
Verified that both probes are set to 1x attenuation.
Ensured the oscilloscope settings match the 1x probe configuration.
Used cursors to isolate one complete cycle of the waveform for accurate RMS calculation. - Ensured the cursors were correctly positioned around the signal period.
Performed a factory reset on the oscilloscope.

Screenshot:
I've attached a picture showing the VRMS measurements at the bottom of the screen. As you can see, CH1 and CH2 are in volts, but the math A - B measurement is incorrectly in gigavolts.


I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with the Rigol DS1202 or other oscilloscopes?
Thank you for your help!

What might Over=***** mean?

Your setup sounds reasonable to me. Have you checked if the vertical resolution of the math channel is also displayed in GV/div? In this case,  you might have overlooked a "hidden" multiplicator in the math function. Otherwise, it looks to me like a software bug. You could  then check if there's a firmware upgrade for your scope or contact rigol directly.

that is just a deleted measurement, can be ignored

thanks Mau, I have contacted Rigol with my same question. Will update here if I get a response.
I can play with the vertical scale which is showing 5V and 10V, so I don't think there is a multiplier there, but good point.

After speaking with support, this is a software bug.
I used another RIGOL oscilloscope and got the correct expected value, that was similar to subtracting RMS_2-RMS_1
